# Question about a proof in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble with this proof in Chapter 8 of Lang's Algebra. I understand most of the proof, all the way up to showing that the transcendence degree of $k(z')$ over $k$ cannot be $r$. However, I don't get the last two lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to the point that you understand, we know that the transcendence degree of $k(z')$ is $\text{tr.deg}_k(k(z') \le r-1$.

On the other hand, since $u_{1n},\ldots ,u_{rn}$ can be written as combinations of $z'$ and $u_{ij}$ where $i=1,\ldots ,r$ , $j=1, \ldots , n-1$, hence (as in the proof)
$$u_{1n},\ldots ,u_{rn} \in k(u_{ij},z' \ | \ i=1,\ldots ,r ,\ j=1, \ldots , n-1)$$

Therefore, $k(u,z')=k(u_{ij},z' \ | \ i=1,\ldots ,r ,\ j=1, \ldots , n) = k(u_{ij},z' \ | \ i=1,\ldots ,r ,\ j=1, \ldots , n-1)$.

Note that $$\text{tr.deg}_k(k(u_{ij},z' \ | \ i=1,\ldots ,r ,\ j=1, \ldots , n-1)) = \text{tr.deg}_k(k(z')) + \text{tr.deg}_{k(z')}(k(u_{ij},z' \ | \ i=1,\ldots ,r ,\ j=1, \ldots , n-1)) \le r-1+r(n-1)=rn-1$$
The last inequation follows since there are $r(n-1)$ elements $u_{ij}$.

Hence, $$\text{tr.deg}_k(k(u)) \le \text{tr.deg}_k(k(u,z')) \le rn-1$$
which is a contradiction since the assumption was $u_{ij}$ are algebraically independent over $k$, i.e, $\text{tr.deg}_k(k(u))=rn$.